# actionscript for loop iterator to change movie clip name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, movieclip

I have a bunch of movie clips I created in flash CS5 and are all placed within the stage. I control each one of them dynamically with code using ActionScript 3. However I want to control all of them at the same time using a for loop and just change the width of each element but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    leftBar+i.width = ( Math.round(channel.rightPeak * 1.1) ) + 60;
}
```

So I have 100 bars each called `leftBar` and their number. So the firstBar is `leftBar1`, then `leftBar2` and so on. I cant get it to work however. I have tried `"leftBar"+i` and also `leftBari` but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to select each of those MovieClips in your loop is:

```
this["leftBar" + i]
```

New code:

```
// Note: We've changed the initial value of i to 1 because you mentioned that
// your first MovieClip was called 'leftBar1' rather than 'leftBar0'.
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var current:MovieClip = this["leftBar" + i];
    current.width = Math.round(channel.rightPeak * 1.1) + 60;
}
```

Basically you want to select the property `leftBar0`, `leftBar1`, etc from `this` using square brackets. It is the same as doing this:

```
this.leftBar0
```

And can also be used for any properties or methods of any other class:

```
// Example of Square Bracket notation.
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

sprite["x"] = 10;
trace(sprite.x);

this["addChild"](sprite);
```

Comment: What if the movie clip is inside another movie clip? Would it be this["barHolder.leftBar" +i]?

Comment: @lomas09 Nope, it would be `barHolder["leftBar" + i]` because each `leftBar` would be a property of `barHolder` rather than `this`.